# The same timestamp in different MySQL versions

Tags: mysql-5.1, mysql-5.6, upgrade

I read in mysql 5.6 SQL changes following text:

> TIMESTAMP columns not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute are
>   assigned the NOT NULL attribute. (Columns of other data types, if not
>   explicitly declared as NOT NULL, permit NULL values.) Setting such a
>   column to NULL sets it to the current timestamp.

(extracted from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

I have tried to create table with following DDL command in both MySQL 5.1 and MySQL 5.6:

```
CREATE table test(
id INT NOT NULL,
my_timestamp TIMESTAMP
);
```

However, I have found that in both databases, `my_timestamp` column is `NOT NULL`. According to the aforementioned sentence, I would expect `my_timestamp` to be `NULL` in older versions (< 5.6). Could somebody explain me this (for me) strange behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation is clear. `TIMESTAMP` columns are by default defined as `NOT NULL`. That was true in 5.5, 5.1 and 5.0 if I remember right. If you read a few lines below that, it states: *"Those nonstandard behaviors **remain** the default for TIMESTAMP but as of MySQL 5.6.6 are deprecated and this warning appears at startup: ..."*

Comment: So why is this mentioned as a change in manual for migration to 5.6?

Comment: See my (edited) comment.

Comment: So this means only that we should everytime explicitly define if column is NULL/NOT NULL? Thank you very much for the explanation, it's now clear to me.

Comment: Yes, it's always better to do that. What changed is that you get a warning at startup. (there are also some changes if you define it as `NULL`, in the docs, below that section)

Comment: You can also now (in 5.6) change this non-standard behaviour with the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` setting/variable.